# statement completion in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

In previous versions of Visual Studio, there used to be a way to automatically complete the statement you were typing, once you had typed enough information. I think it was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, but I'm not sure. It would add any missing quotes, parentheses and semicolons, then open a new line underneath.

Is there a way to do that in VS 2013? Or maybe that was only for C++ and I'm now using C#?

Comment: Intellisense? Code Snippets? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx

Comment: You're talking about [Intellisense](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b.aspx) which is a feature of Visual Studio. It's still in 2013.

Comment: In VS2013, go to `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Intellisense` and make sure it's turned on

Comment: "add any missing quotes, parentheses and semicolons" - sounds more like a snippet or something like [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways in VS 2013:

- way 1: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>
- way 2: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>

More detailed information please see this link:
http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2013/